# mod unknown in a list of equations with all knowns

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have these equations
$a = b \bmod c$ and 
$d = e \bmod c$ and
$f = g \bmod c$

all are known except $c$
can I solve for $c$?
ie: is there a unique solution assuming all $a,b,d,e,f$ are not equal

Comment: The vote to close the question as off-topic is absurd.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I intended to vote for missing context or other details.  It appears I mis-clicked.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the solutions for $c$ are all those $c$ such that
$$
\newcommand{\div}{\; \mid \;}
c \div b - a, e - d, g - f
$$
i.e.
$$
c \div \gcd(b-a, e-d, g-f)
$$

Thus there is a unique solution if and only if
$$
\gcd(b-a, e-d, g-f) = 1.
$$

Comment: lets say they are not equal, can you point me to an article or anything that says there is no unique solution.. thanks

Comment: @user1510863 There could be a unique solution.  If you want to ask a different question than the one you asked, you should edit it to specify what you meant.

Comment: @user1510863 For instance if $b = a + 1$, then of course there is a unique solution.  It seems to me you have not thought this problem through very hard yourself.

Comment: In general: How do we solve a set of equations like this?

Comment: Thanks Goos very much .. now I understand the condition for the unique solution as you showed, so how do we actually solve for the unique solution after gcd = 1

Comment: @user1510863 I think you can figure that out yourself.

Comment: Goos please bear with me.. I am trying to solve something like: $cx + a = b$ and $cy + d = e$ where $c,x,y$ are unknowns .. I really dont know how to solve for $c$

Comment: @user1510863 No, seriously.  If you are still confused ask a new question.  It should be clear in my answer what is the unique solution from what I wrote and from what the symbol $|$ means.

Comment: @user1510863 **Ask a new question**.