# unique solution for mod equation

Tags: modular-arithmetic

If I have these equations
$a\equiv b \pmod c$

$d\equiv e \pmod c$
All known except $c$

and $\gcd(b−a,e−d)=1$

how do I find the unique solution for $c$?

and if the gcd!= 1  how do I find some possible solutions?

Comment: $\gcd(b-a,e-d)=1 \implies c=1$, $\gcd(b-a,e-d)\neq1 \implies c\neq1$.

Comment: how do I solve for c?

Comment: Look, $b-a$ and $e-d$ are both divisible by $c$. So their greatest common divisor is $1$ if and only if $c=1$.

Comment: I understand.. so the only unique solution for c = 1, how do I find other possible solutions if gcd!=1

Comment: Well, the gcd is necessarily a multiple of $c$. If it's $1$ or any other prime number, then obviously $c$ is equal to that gcd. Otherwise, $c$ is equal to one of the (not necessarily prime) divisors of that gcd. In fact, the last sentence holds in the general case: $c$ is simply one of the divisors of the gcd. You can iterate `for (int c=gcd; c>0; c--)` until you find a $c$ for which $a \equiv b \pmod c$ and $d \equiv e \pmod c$.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by iterate.. any divisor for (b-a, and e-d) is a possible solution for C , there is no unique solution, correct

Comment: @user1510863 Generally $\,c\,$ satisfies the system of congruences  iff $\,c\mid\gcd(a-b,d-e),\,$ see the equivalences in my answer. So the solution set is the set of (positive) divisors of the gcd.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/789739/mod-unknown-in-a-list-of-equations-with-all-knowns

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{eqnarray}{\bf Hint}\qquad\quad a\equiv b\!\!\pmod{\! c}\\d\equiv e\!\!\pmod{\! c}\end{eqnarray}\iff $ $\begin{eqnarray} c\mid a-b\\c\mid d-e\end{eqnarray}\iff c\mid\gcd(a-b,d-e)$

This first equivalence is by definition of congruence, and the second is the [universal gcd property](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/198801/242).

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, $c$ can be any of the (not necessarily prime) divisors of the $gcd$.

So you can simply pick $c=gcd(b-a,e-d)$.

Comment: Thanks. C could be the largest divisors, but it doesn't have to right? ie gcd is one solution

Comment: Yep, I removed the "largest" restriction...

Answer (score 0):

$$b-a=mc\\d-e=nc\\gcd(b-a,d-e)=c*gcd(m,n)=1\\c=gcd(m,n)=1$$